# How to use Concat function in form page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

```
%%[ 
        set @travelinterest= RequestParameter("tli")

        set @travelinterest1= RequestParameter("tli1")

        set @travelinterest2= RequestParameter("tli2")

        set @travelinterest3= RequestParameter("tli3")

        set @travelinterest4= RequestParameter("tli4")

        set @travelinterest5= RequestParameter("tli5")

        set @travelinterest6= RequestParameter("tli6")

        set @travelinterest7= RequestParameter("tli7")

        set @travelinterest8= RequestParameter("tli8")

        set @travelinterest9= RequestParameter("tli9")

        set @travelinterest10= RequestParameter("tli10")

        set @travelinterest11= RequestParameter("tli11")

        set @travelinterest12= RequestParameter("tli12")

        set @favouritebcdestination = RequestParameter("bcd")

        set @email = "testingprupose1@gmail.com" 


    UpdateDE("B2CSubscribe_AN",1,"Email",@email,"Travelinterest", Concat(@travelinterest,";",@travelinterest1,";",@travelinterest2,";", @travelinterest3,";",@travelinterest4,";",@travelinterest5),"Favouritebcdestination",Replace(@favouritebcdestination,",",";"))
    ]%%
```

> In form page i have to concetanate all the travel interest values
>   which does not have empty value , if one travel interest value is
>   empty,then i want to skip and update the remaining twelve values, if
>   three travel interest values are empty update the remaining 10 values
>   using concat function i have tried  , but logic is not coming anyone
>   please help with code, if i want to check all conditions, i used to 10
>   updateDE function? guide me with sample code?

someone suggests me :
**Why not just do a javascript if(this.checked) function to fill in a hidden input field when each box is checked. This would remove any need to concat or do anything server-side as it would already be in a single field**

How to use javascript ? for this scenario help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use JavaScript, you can easily achieve this with AMPscript. This code should do the trick:

```js
%%[ 
var @travelinterest, @travelinterest1, @travelinterest2, @travelinterest3
var @travelinterest4, @travelinterest5, @travelinterest6, @travelinterest7
var @travelinterest8, @travelinterest9, @travelinterest10, @travelinterest11
var @travelinterest12, @favouritebcdestination
var @email, @interestsTemp, @interests

set @travelinterest= RequestParameter("tli")
set @travelinterest1= RequestParameter("tli1")
set @travelinterest2= RequestParameter("tli2")
set @travelinterest3= RequestParameter("tli3")
set @travelinterest4= RequestParameter("tli4")
set @travelinterest5= RequestParameter("tli5")
set @travelinterest6= RequestParameter("tli6")
set @travelinterest7= RequestParameter("tli7")
set @travelinterest8= RequestParameter("tli8")
set @travelinterest9= RequestParameter("tli9")
set @travelinterest10= RequestParameter("tli10")
set @travelinterest11= RequestParameter("tli11")
set @travelinterest12= RequestParameter("tli12")
set @favouritebcdestination = RequestParameter("bcd")
set @email = "testingprupose1@gmail.com" 

set @interestsTemp = concat(
    iif(empty(@travelinterest),'',concat(@travelinterest,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest1),'',concat(@travelinterest1,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest2),'',concat(@travelinterest2,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest3),'',concat(@travelinterest3,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest4),'',concat(@travelinterest4,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest5),'',concat(@travelinterest5,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest6),'',concat(@travelinterest6,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest7),'',concat(@travelinterest7,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest8),'',concat(@travelinterest8,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest9),'',concat(@travelinterest9,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest10),'',concat(@travelinterest10,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest11),'',concat(@travelinterest11,';')),
    iif(empty(@travelinterest12),'',concat(@travelinterest12,';'))
    )

/*remove trailing semicolon*/
set @interests = substring(@interestsTemp,1,subtract(length(@interestsTemp),1))

UpdateDE("B2CSubscribe_AN",1,
        "Email",@email,
        "Travelinterest",@interests,
        "Favouritebcdestination",Replace(@favouritebcdestination,",",";"))
]%%
```

Comment: last occuring semicolon @Eliot Harper

Comment: @SFDC, I deliberately omitted that as I assume that they don't want to include a semicolon delimiter after the last value. e.g, my code will return `France;Germany;Spain` not `France;Germany;Spain;`.

Comment: your code is working only for last value if i check, if i check intermediate value and i am not checking last value , then semicolon occuring

Comment: @EliotHarper I have one doubt in Regex- i have tried %%[
outputLine(concat("<h4>Replace parenthetical text with space</h4>"))
set @s = "whee (whatever it is) whoop;"
set @p = "\;\";"
set @m = RegExMatch(@s, @p, 0 , "IgnoreCase")
set @o = replace(@s,@m, " ")
outputLine(concat("input:  ",@s,"<br>"))
outputLine(concat('pattern: "',@p,'"<br>'))
outputLine(concat("match: ",@m,"<br>"))
outputLine(concat("replaced: ",@o,"<br>"))
The output is  = v(@o)

]%%, i want  to replace semicolon with comma from above sentence, what pattern i have to give? please help me

Comment: I have little confusion in regex , can you please help

Comment: Please can you create a new question for your RegExMatch function query.